# Почему письма, отправленные через PHP, приходят во все сервисы, кроме Outlook?

Tags: php, email

Есть простой скрипт отправки письма на PHP:

```
<?php
  
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Sender Name <noreply@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'>' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  
  $mailto = 'email@domain.com';
  
  $formID = trim($_POST['formID']);
  $name = trim($_POST['name']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
  $message = trim($_POST['message']);
  
  if ($formID == 'form1') {
    $subject = 'Заявка с сайта 1';
  } else {
    $subject = 'Заявка с сайта 2';
  }
  
  $message = 'Имя: '.$name.'<br> E-mail: '.$email.'<br> Телефон: '.$phone.'<br><br> Суть вопроса: <br>'.$message;
  
  mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
  
?>
```

Письма, отправленные через этот скрипт, приходят в gmail, yandex и т.п.
Но не приходят в Outlook-почту на своем домене.

В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что аутлук, например, взял да и забанил почту или весь домен отправителя.